# indexing into a S4 function

Tags: r

I would like to obtain the result from point 3. by indexing the e object into the function, however I am unfortunate in this as per I can not find a way to do it.

```
# 1. 
e <- sapply(RESULT,attributes)$names
[1] "d2"  "s2"  "d4"  "s4"  "d6"     

# 2. - provide info on the object e 
is(sapply(RESULT,attributes)$names)
[1] "character" "vector" "data.frameRowLabels" "SuperClassMethod"  "atomicVector" "index"

# 3.
RESULT[[1]]$d2
[1]  0.7934296  0.5616185  0.3541667  0.1675481 -0.1092148 

# 4. - provide info on function
is(RESULT[[1]]$d2)
[1] "numeric" "vector" "atomicVector" "index" "number" "numLike" "replValue"

# I need to index and place each element without quotes in the following function after $ (S4 object) as to obtain the following vector.
# My goal is to place the below result indexed into the above function by means of indexing the sequence to the vector below.

d <- seq(1:length(sapply(RESULT,attributes)$names))

# However I get the following result.
RESULT[[1]]$noquote(e[[1]])
Error: tentativa de aplicar una no-función
noquote(e[[1]])
[1] d2
```

How should I go along indexing e at the end of the function object and also remove the quotes as to work.

Comment: have a look at `?seq_along` for one thing. Would you try writing out what you think your result should look like, in terms of elements of e?

Comment: For reference, hadley's [chapter on s4](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html) in advanced R is pretty nice.

Comment: The result should be the same as in point 3. My question is about how to index into an S4 object function the vector e, the issue is how to remove the quotes in a way that is accepted by the function in point 3